# How to add an order(autoIncrement) property to collection using Linq?

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

Having:

Initialize an anonymouse collection (I would send it as json)

```
var myCollection = new[]
{
    new
    {
        Code = 0,
        Name = "",
        OtherAttribute = ""
    }

}.ToList();

myCollection.Clear();
```

And get the data.

```
myCollection = (from iPeople in ctx.Person
                join iAnotherTable in ctx.OtherTable
                on iPeople.Fk equals iAnotherTable.FK
                ...
                order by iPeople.Name ascending
                select new
                {
                    Code = iPeople.Code,
                    Name = iPeople.Name,
                    OtherAttribute = iAnotherTable.OtherAtribute
                }).ToList();
```

I want to add an Identity column, I need the collection ordered and a counted from 1 to collection.count. Is for binding this counter to a Column in a table (jtable).

```
var myCollection = new[]
{
    new
    {
        Identity = 0,
        Code = 0,
        Name = "",
        OtherAttribute = ""
    }

}.ToList();

myCollection = (from iPeople in ctx.Person
                join iAnotherTable in ctx.OtherTable
                on iPeople.Fk equals iAnotherTable.FK
                ...
                order by iPeople.Name ascending
                select new
                {
                    Identity = Enum.Range(1 to n)//Here I don´t know how to do; in pl/sql would be rownum, but in Linq to SQL how?
                    Code = iPeople.Code,
                    Name = iPeople.Name,
                    OtherAttribute = iAnotherTable.OtherAtribute
                }).ToList();
```

Comment: You may be overthinking this. Is there anything stopping you from using a local counter variable to set the identity? E.g: `Identity = counter++` ?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Nothing but I don't want to iterate again the whole list after get it.
If I can do it using Linq, will be great.

Comment: You don't have to iterate again .. you can do it inside the LINQ query - as I demonstrated in my last comment.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using linq to entities or linq to sql, get your data from the server and ToList() it.
Most likely this answer will not translate to sql but I have not tried it.

```
List<string> myCollection = new List<string>();
myCollection.Add("hello");
myCollection.Add("world");
var result = myCollection.Select((s, i) => new { Identity = i, Value = s }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

As Simon stated in his comments, consider the following, albeit contrived, example:

```
int i = 0;
var collection = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(x => new { Id = ++i });
```

Comment: Why then not just `Select(x => new { Id = x });` ?

Comment: @Roy, the idea here was to use an external count `i` that could be incremented `i++` in the `Select()`. Of course you could just use `x` in my example, but the OP's source collection is not an `Enumerable.Range` construct. This is why I said it was a contrived example :)

Answer (score 1):

As Simon suggest in comment, that could would look like below:

```
int counter = 0; //or 1.
myCollection = (from iPeople in ctx.Person
            join iAnotherTable in ctx.OtherTable
            on iPeople.Fk equals iAnotherTable.FK
            ...
            order by iPeople.Name ascending
            select new
            {
                Identity = counter++,
                Code = iPeople.Code,
                Name = iPeople.Name,
                OtherAttribute = iAnotherTable.OtherAtribute
            }).ToList();
```

Is there any problem in executing this kind of code?

Comment: yes it throws me `An expression tree may not contain an assignment operator`

Answer (score 0):

One solution that helped me to achieve the same goal:
Create a separate Function like this:

```cs
        private int getMaterialOrder(ref int order)
        {
            return order++;
        }
```

Then call it in your linq query like:

```cs
...
 select new MaterialItem() { Order=getMaterialOrder(ref order), 
...
```